# How do I store a value from a SELECT statement in a variable in a MySQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

This may be a super easy question to answer, but I am unsure how to do this correctly.

Here is my query within the procedure:

```
SELECT COUNT(barcode) AS count FROM movieitems;
```

How do I store the return value of this statement (for example, the value in `count` is `5`) into a variable? I want to be able to access the `count` value throughout the rest of my procedure.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In a stored procedure do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(barcode) AS count into @myVar FROM movieitems;
```

Comment: ERROR 1327 (42000) at line 5: Undeclared variable: some_var. - I am getting this error. How to solve this.

Comment: @GauravGupta You need to declare it. Use `DECLARE @myVar INT` , depending on the type of variable that you need.

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT @someVariable := COUNT(barcode) FROM movie ...
```

You can then use `@someVariable` in other queries.
E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_field > @someVariable;
```

And you can also manipulate the variable using `SET`:

```
SET @someVariable = @someVariable + 1;
```

Comment: its showing "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" after using this in a stoerd procedure